# HTML - Fuente y estilo personalizado no funcionando correctamente

Tags: html, css, web

Buenas, tengo una web-galeria de arte con varias partes. En todas ellas tengo definido un header que usa una fuente customizada, sin embargo en algunas se muestra bien y en otras no. Para comprobarlo esta es mi web:

http://164.132.103.92/index.php es la pagina principal, se ve correctamente. La pagina de contacto también se ve bien.
http://164.132.103.92/imagen.php y la pagina de comparador cambian el estilo de la letra, haciendo que se vea fatal. Alguna idea de que podría ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado el problema. Era un orden de tags. Aparentemente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

El orden de los dos tags cambia totalmente el estilo de la web.

Comment: Eso es debido a que muchas veces los estilos de algunas librerías tienen más prioridad que los estilos de una hoja de css "normal". De esta manera, si los pones los últimos van a sobreescribir todo lo demás. Cuando sean estilos pon tus estilos los últimos para que sean los que más preferencia tengan (hay veces que ni aún así y necesitarás "jugar" con la prioridad del css).

Answer (score 1):

He revisado la página, y he encontrado `13 errores` en tu documento `HTML`

> line 18 column 169 - Error: Bad value “http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic” for attribute “href” on element “link”: Illegal character in query: “|” is not allowed.

Con este error, ya te esta diciendo que no te va cargar tus fuentes correctamente, has añadido el caracter `|` a tu url de vinculación de fonts google apis, que no esta permitida.

Podras instalar el `Complemento` de firefoxs `HTML Validator`, para asi revisar tu documento HTML para que sea valido en **W3C** algo importante para el SEO.

> En la página **index.php** tambien tienes bastantes errores en tu HTML, te aconsejo que primero miras bien como utilizar las etiquetas HTML, te dejo la página de **W3C** donde explican como utilizar cada etiqueta HTML.

[HTML5 Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Comment: Vale, enredando un poco en el codigo he visto que esa fuente no me la esta cogiendo, pero si me coge otra que es Lato, que es la que se ve en la pagina principal, y sin embargo, a pesar de que el css es identico, en las otras paginas esta puesta Helvetica. Debe de ser un problema de estilos asignados

Comment: A veces aunque tengas errores en tu documento, funcionan en algunas navegadores si y en otros no, pero siempre es importante para un correcto SEO, que sea limpio el codigo HTML, como por ejemplo añadir un atributo alt a tus imagenes, etc.