# Error con Fuentes en mi sitio web [No se muestran]

Tags: html, css, fuentes

Le estoy haciendo un sitio web a mi hermano https://amparandotusalud.com
Se me presenta el siguiente problema (adjunto imagen)

> En mi computadora, y en todas las que probé (asi como celulares) la página se ve bien. Mas allá de algunos detalles que hay que ir modificando para cada caso, todo va normal.

Cuando mi hermano mira la página en su notebook, con Google Chrome a una resolucion de 1280*768, la barra de navegacion del sitio aparece sin texto. Si yo pongo esa misma resolución en mi compu, entro por Chrome, yo puedo verlo sin problemas. Ya ingresé a su pc por teamviewer, me fijé de reiniciar caché y todo eso. Les muestro como tengo el código y una imagen de lo que pasa:

> (todo esto en la pc que se ve el problema, por medio de teamviewer) Primero se observa el nav en blanco. Luego abro el inspector, y le doy uncheck a la clase que le dá la tipografía al nav. Ahora el problema se corrige. La cosa es que yo quisiera que esta fuente de la imagen, se vea unicamente cuando la fuente no se carga.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Asi es como tengo las fuentes colocadas en el CSS

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Roboto-Light;
   src: url('../fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf');
}


nav{
   font-family: "Roboto-Light", Georgia, Serif;
}
```

> Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya intentaste ponerle `!important` ?

Comment: Ahi lo probe, la cosa es q lo tengo que probar en "produccion" digamos para verlo desde la pc que esta a 500km de aca. https://www.amparandotusalud.com/css/style.css Todavia no me actualiza el css, no se a que se puede deber eso. Generalmente hostinger tarda en actualizar estas cosas. En breve te digo si se soluciono, gracias

Comment: awanta... por lo que veo... no te carga la fuente, posiblemente está mal la ruta, en firefox hay un tab fonts. Y una parte que dice All fonts on page, si no te sale allí tu fuente, es que no la pudo cargar. Disculpa pensé que te salía como a la derecha en vez de como a la izquierda, y te recomiendo poner siempre una fuente de remplazo por si la primera no carga lo sepas inmediatamente.

Comment: adicionalmente te recomiendo revisar las preguntas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104808/como-inserto-una-fuente-en-css y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33542/html-fuente-y-estilo-personalizado-no-funcionando-correctamente porque roboto casi siempre se usaba con bootstrap :)

Comment: es la misma fuente que utilizo para el texto de toda la pagina, eso es mas raro todavia

Comment: Revisa la clase `.custom-nav` que la estas aplicando al elemento `nav` tiene un `z-index: 999` y un background color blanco. No sera que el elemento te esta encimando los otros elementos por el z-index? Estoy chekando en my chrome y aqui veo perfectamente bien la barra de navegacion a diferentes resoluciones.

Comment: uh chekando otra vez, la barra de navegacion desaparece por completo a `990px` de ancho; y no me muestra el botton de `menu` hasta alrededor de los `770px` por lo que hay un espacio en blanco donde el usuario no puede accessar la navegacion.

Comment: @xelfury muchas gracias, ahi estuve revisando y aplique algunas configuraciones para diferentes pantallas. El problema estaba con la clase "font-weight-bold" de bootstrap. El codigo de esa clase es ``font-weight:700 !important`` y no me funciona. Las letras de Roboto solo se muestran (repito, este problema me sucede unicamente en una computadora, en chrome con una resolucion de 1280x1024) cuando weight-bold es igual o inferior a 400. Ni se que toque la verdad jaja, creo que use la fuente original de boostrap o no se, pero quedo todo mas en "negrita" el sitio en general, pero ahora se ve bien

Comment: @xelfury ademas el problema que tenia por el cual no se reflejaba el cambio en el .css tiene que ver con mi red. Los del hosting me dicen que ellos lo ven al cambio, que intente cambiar mi ip y lo iba a poder ver. Cuando me conecte con la red wifi de mi vecino el cambio en el css se aplico instantaneamente. Esa configuracion que desconozco (limpie cache de todas las formas que conozco) es la que no me permite ver los cambios reflejados al instante. Probe con ctrl+f5, ctrl+shift+R, Clear Caché extension, ventana de incognito, otro browser, etc. y nada